# Read closed facebook groups

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-group

I would like to read (and if possible post to) two closed Facebook groups on behalf of an application. I have only been able to read as a user member of a group, but that doesn't quite satisfy. Can someone help me find the correct API-call and permission please?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a closed group is that only specific people (at the discretion of the current members) are allowed access to it.  Your app will not be able to access the group.  If you want an app to make posts, etc that members can see, your best bet is to make an app page that people can like instead.

Comment: Thank you for responding!
I understand the thought behind it, it makes perfect sense after all. The way I thought about it was that if a user gave the app permissions the app would be allowed inside the group if the user was a member of it, but perhaps that is not possible?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I'm guessing that Facebook don't want you using Groups this way and would rather you use an App page which they can put advertising on.